# C# loop through sets of items in list

Tags: c#, list

I have list of Strings, sometimes over 10.000.000 strings in the list.

I need to loop through the list and send chunks of this data to an API, a sublist of 2k strings per API-call.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Do you have that complete list in memory, literally as a `List<string>`? Can you just use indexes? What have you tried so far? (Contrary to a previous version of this comment, it looks like LINQ to Objects does *not* optimize Skip, so just using Skip/Take repeatedly will be slow. There are various other LINQ-related options though...)

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) operator wisely with variables.

For example syntax will be something like below-

```
IEnumerable<resultStrings> page1 = myStrings.Skip(0).Take(2000);            
IEnumerable<resultStrings> page2 = myStrings.Skip(2000).Take(2000);
```

Comment: With 10million strings this is extremely slow.

Comment: Agree. But this is the first take till more elaboration on question evolves :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try GetRange method:

```
        List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        var chunk = 2;
        var iterations = list.Count / chunk;

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            var portion = list.GetRange(chunk * i, chunk);
            //Do API
        }

        var remainder = list.GetRange(chunk * iterations, list.Count - chunk * iterations);
        //Do API
```

You can look at some benchmark test on GetRange vs Take where GetRange wins.
https://icodeit.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/performance-of-skip-and-take-in-linq-to-objects/

Comment: But `GetRange` needs to create new lists in-memory over and over againwhereas `Skip`/`Take` just need CPU and no additional memory. OP  must decide what's more important.

Comment: ++ But in most cases this should be the most efficient and straight-forward approach.

Comment: Yes, but if there is list of reference types, memory consumption will be not that big i think

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most efficient approach is to use a database instead of loading all into memory(from wherever) and then use `Skip`/`Take` to take parts of it.

However, you could use `GroupBy`:

```
var chunks = largeStringList.Select((str, index) => new { str, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2000, x => x.str);
foreach (var chunkGroup in chunks)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", chunkGroup));
```

I've run a little performance test with this result:

[`List.GetRange`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274749/284240):

```
00:00:00.0404119 (40 milliseconds)
```

(my) [`GroupBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274828/284240):

```
00:00:02.2386504 (two seconds)
```

[`Skip`/`Take`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274598/284240):

```
00:10:11.6467726 (yes, more than 10 minutes)
```